# How to check if a value was selected from <select>?

Tags: php, jquery, select

I am trying to update the content of a `<div>` when a new value is chosen from a `<select>` element, but my current code is not working. With my current code, the div is being updated every time I click the `<select>`. How can I fix that?

This is my js code:

```
// Month PROCESS 
$(function(){
    $('select[name=month]').click(function(e) {
        $('<img src="../images/loading.gif" id="loading" style="width:auto;" />').appendTo("#mes");

        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get the A tag

        var month = $( 'select[name=month]' ).val();

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"pages/daily-process.php",
            data: {mid: month},
            dataType: 'html',
            target: '#dateProcess',
            success: function(data){
                $("#mes").find('img#loading').remove();
                $("#mes").html(data);
            }
        })

    }); 
});
```

And the html:

```
<div id="dateProcess">
<select name="month">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<div id='mes'></div>
</div>
```

This is the daily-process.php

```
<?php

    $getMonth = $_GET['mid'];
    $getYear = $_GET['yid'];

    $begin = new DateTime( $getYear.'-'.$getMonth.'-01' );
    $end = new DateTime( $getYear.'-'.$getMonth.'-31' );
    $end = $end->modify( '+1 day' );

    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

    foreach($daterange as $date){
        echo $date->format("F d, Y") . "<br />";
    }
?>
```

Comment: you have `$getYear = $_GET['yid'];` but you are not sending `yid` in the post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I undertand the question correctly, you are using the wrong event.

You should use `change` instead of `click`:

```
$('select[name=month]').change( //...
```

Comment: I think that $('select[name=month]').on('change', function() { /*...*/ }); is now the preferred way of doing this.

Comment: @ridecar2 Not really. `.change` is a perfectly valid shortcut for the code you suggested. BTW, if new `<select>` elements with the same name were to be added dynamically, neither version would work. You'd need to delegate the event like this: `$(document).on('change', 'select[name=month]', function() { /*...*/ });`.